# Batch file to clone ArcGIS Pro Python env

Tags: python, arcgis-pro, conda

I want to create a batch file that will clone the default ArcGIS Pro python environment and install boto3 to help set up new PCs.

I can clone the environment with the following batch, however I cannot activate it and it tries to install boto3 on the default environment:

```
::set credentials
SET "username=xxxxx"
SET "password=xxxxx"

::set proxies
SET HTTP_PROXY=http://%username%:%password%@web-prdproxy-usr.dmz:80
SET HTTPS_PROXY=http://%username%:%password%@web-prdproxy-usr.dmz:80

::activate existing env
C:
cd "C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\Scripts"
CALL activate.bat 

::clone env
conda create --clone arcgispro-py3  -p C:\PyEnvironments\arcgispro-py3-clone

::activate new environment
conda activate C:\PyEnvironments\arcgispro-py3-clone

::install boto3
conda install boto3
```

The error message I get is as follows:

```
CommandNotFoundError: Your shell has not been properly configured to use 'conda activate'.
If using 'conda activate' from a batch script, change your
invocation to 'CALL conda.bat activate'.
```

I have tried to to call the activate.bat again as well as proenv.bat but neither seems to make a difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved by calling activate.bat again with the new environment on a single line - troubleshooting earlier I had called activate.bat and then used conda activate after that which was giving the same error.

```
::set credentials
SET "username=xxxxx"
SET "password=xxxxx"

::set proxies
SET HTTP_PROXY=http://%username%:%password%@web-prdproxy-usr.dmz:80
SET HTTPS_PROXY=http://%username%:%password%@web-prdproxy-usr.dmz:80

::activate existing env
C:
cd "C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\Scripts"
CALL activate.bat 

::clone env
conda create --clone arcgispro-py3  -p C:\PyEnvironments\arcgispro-py3-clone

::activate new environment
CALL activate.bat C:\PyEnvironments\arcgispro-py3-clone

::install boto3
conda install boto3
```